# Unable to load data from jitterbit to salesforce

Tags: mysql, utf-8, salesforce, special-characters, jitterbit

We are trying to load data from mysql database to salesforce through **Jitterbit(v: 8.16.13.1)** on **windows 2012 R2 machine**.

We have created mysql view using Jitterbit cloud data loader to load the view data to salesforce objects.

We have UTf8 special characters for eg:  .Ã,®,Ø,ÿ in the database field.

But when we try to Upsert data we get following error

```
Error
The operation "Upsert Investments (3)" failed.Error: Failed to read JDBC source. 
Database Error: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x80\xC3\x82\xC2\x99...' for column '_input_string' at row 1  
SQL: SELECT `name`,`website` FROM `table_name...`
```

Please help in fixing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not much help, but have you tried wrapping the values in the String() function before trying to send them?  That has helped me on occasion when I've run into slightly similar issues.

Comment: C280 and C382 are not, I think, valid UTF8 characters.  Where did the string come from?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this article in [Jitterbit success central](https://success.jitterbit.com/display/CS/Database). Jitterbit does not support those types of characters. The database driver is the issue. Not your script. so you will have to convert before you push up into Salesforce.  find out what Salesforce reads, like HTML encoding values. you might have to convert it into HTML if it does. [HTML encoding helper](https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder)